# Eclipse step into debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, step-into

I just put eclipse on my laptop, and when I use the Step Into debugging tool, it doesn't just take me to the next part of my code. An example is if I call `.size();` on an array list, it will take me into the array list class and through all the code required for `.size();`

However on my desktop it will simply take me to my next piece of code. I do:

```
System.out.println("hello world!");
```

If i click "Step Into" on that (from my desktop), *hello world* will appear the console.

To contrast that, if I "Step Into" `System.out.println("hellow world");` on my laptop, it first pulls up PrintStream.class, then after much clicking Writter.class comes up, then String.class, then BufferedWritter.class, etc.

I have been just using "Step Over" when debugging, however there are some calls, a basic example would be `mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.size());` where if I step over that, it will just skip the entire thing, but if I step into it, it will pull up the `arr.size();` method and I will have to click through all of that before getting back to my stuff.

On my desktop I am running windows and eclipse version 3.4.1. On my laptop I am running linux and eclipse version 3.5.1.

Thoughts? Advice? Does that make sense?

Comment: "Step out of" might be your friend.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably have the step filters enabled to skip java.*, which would skip over any standard java classes.

There is a Use Step Filters toggle on your debug display, it's a two headed arrow, right and down.

Comment: was about to get crazy toggling "use step filter" in the preferences ;-) without noticing said icon in the debug view toolbar

Comment: Oh man thank you so much! You cannot imagine how much annoyance you have saved me from :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can click the "Use Step Filters" button on the debug view toolbar to skip over built-in packages during debugging. You can configure which packages are stepped over in the preferences (Java > Debug > Step Filtering).