# Source not found when debugging constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am an experienced .NET and Visual Studio developer who's trying to switch to Java and Eclipse. I am a newbie to Eclipse.

I am having a hard time debugging my Java programs. The "step into" debugging function always results in a "Source not found" error message with an "Edit Source Lookup Path" button whenever I try to **step into** a constructor. I've just installed Eclipse Enterprise Edition and not messed around with any settings.

Even debugging inner classes results in this error. Consider this code:

```
public class HelloWorld {   
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        class JustForTesting {
        public String s;
        public JustForTesting() {
        s = "Just a test";
        }
    }   
    JustForTesting n = new JustForTesting();
     System.out.println("Hello World! " + n.s);
  }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint at line 9 and try to step into the constructor (line 5) it says `"Source not found"`. The title of the window is `Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 24` Quite unbelievable as the code obviously resides in the same file!

Answer (score 5):

It's not so much an Eclipse thing and more of a Java thing.  When you construct any class for the first time Java needs to load the class.  If you get into that situation again just do a step-return (this will finish loading the class) and then do step-into again (this will go into your constructor).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your suggestion did the trick! So this behavior is by design?? Coming from the .NET world I must say I am surprised as it adds a lot of annoyances when debugging. I've never experienced anything like it using Visual Studio.

Comment: I'll agree it's annoying.  There is a way, using step filters, to prevent it from happening.  Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268902/eclipse-step-into-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Just Below **Source not found** error you will see "**Edit Source Lookup Path**" button click on it and then click on Add button then Java Project and include your project .. Hope this will solve your problem