# Eclipse error: Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse. When I try to debug my main class I get Launcher$AppClassLoader class not found. This post [Source not found when debugging constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807607/source-not-found-when-debugging-constructor) says "Just Below Source not found error you will see "Edit Source Lookup Path" button click on it and then click on Add button then Java Project and include your project .. Hope this will solve your problem."

So I did that and added my project, like this. What debugging steps come next?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that is what you want, but you can filter out classes which you don't want to debug like ClassLoader, or you don't have access to its sources.
I generally don't want to test standard classes placed in `java`, `javax`, or `sun` packages.

To do this just go to `Windows`->`Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Debug` -> `Step Filtering` and configure which packages or classes you want to skip.

[image]

Just make sure that while debugging step filtering is toggled on

[image]