# Why doesn't 'step into' debugging work with my Eclipse 4.5.2? (Step filters deactivated)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I want to step through some classes of the Oracle JDK implementation using the Eclipse debugger.

So I downloaded the current JDK from Oracle (jdk1.8.0_77), installed Eclipse via the Windows installer and wrote a simple HelloWorld class.

However, when using the 'Step into' debugging command steps over the lines that invocate JDK methods like System.out.println.

I configured Eclipse to use the JRE that is contained within the JDK instead of the standard JRE and ensured that step filters are neither set in the preferences nor applied in the debug view as explained in these answers:

[Eclipse step into debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268902/eclipse-step-into-debugging)

[How can I step into a core java class method in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742097/how-can-i-step-into-a-core-java-class-method-in-eclipse)

So why doesn't 'Step into (F5)' step into the source?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by going to **Debug Configurations** -> **JRE** -> **Alternate JRE** -> choose jdk installation instead of default jre, and then run the debug with that configuration.
 I am using Eclipse Neon 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works now. I had previously installed Eclipse Mars.2 EE edition via the Eclipse installer. I also downloaded the standard edition as zip file and it didn't work neither. I finally tried out Eclipse Neon now and it works out of the box.

I will do a clean Mars.2 installation on another device later to let you know though its a problem with the version of Eclipse or my laptop configuration.